# How to client SSL certificate for iOS app for React native project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, ssl-certificate, nsurlsession

I have clients cloudflare SSL certificate(.pem). I want to embed this SSL certificate for my react native project for **iOS** so that we can access our API's. I am new to this I have tried so many ways but didn't get exact solution for it.

The language we are using is Objective C where we have to write code for SSL cert embedding.
Can anyone help me with this any tutorial link will work for me to get reference.

I have tried to convert cert into .p12 but when I decode response and call our API I am getting 403 error code. I want try same cert which client gave me .pem I dont want to convert it to somethingelse

Comment: This is a very open question. Am I guessing right that you are trying to get mTLS (Mutual Transport Layer Security) to work? That means you have the private key also on your client? (I guess you won't develop your application for the appstore?)

Comment: Correct I get this certificate form client so both have same keys.